# Change the colour of plot and axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code:

```
y = [1.53333333, 1.08333333, 1.11666667, 0.68333333, 0.83333333, 0.46666667]
x = [0.5, 1]

plt.plot(x, y[0:2], color = "red")
plt.plot(x, y[2:4], color = "blue")
plt.plot(x, y[4:6], color = "yellow")
plt.ylabel("Time (s)")
plt.xlabel("Conditions (degrees)")
plt.legend(['0 metres', '4 metres', '8 metres'], loc = 'upper right')
plt.xlim(0.5, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 3)
plt.show()
```

Which generates the following plot:

[image]

However the colours are the opposite to what I want (I want white background with black tick marks, text and axes). I have attempted to change the background using the following:

```
plt.plot(x, y[0:2], color = "red")
plt.plot(x, y[2:4], color = "blue")
plt.plot(x, y[4:6], color = "yellow")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('white')
plt.ylabel("Reaction time (s)")
plt.xlabel("Heading onditions (degrees)")
plt.legend(['0 metres', '4 metres', '8 metres'], loc = 'upper right')
plt.xlim(0.5, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 3)
plt.show()
```

However it produces this:

[image]
Does anybody know how I would get the whole image to be white, with black axes, tick markers and labels. I'm running this code in Visual Code Studio if that makes a difference.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Upon running your code I get a plot with a white background.

Comment: @FarhoodET that's strange. Are you aware of any default settings which can change the appearance of plots? What programme are you running the code from?

Comment: Are you using the dark background style in matplotlib? Because I could reproduce your problem with a `matplotlib.style.use('dark_background')` flag at the start of my program.

Comment: See this: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/users/dflt_style_changes.html

Comment: @FarhoodET that's great sorted it, thank you!